Как в Python создать папку с определенным именем на диске C?
Мне для игры надо, чтобы текст записался в папку Games на диске C, но у некоторых может не быть этой папки, так что мне надо создать ее. Можно ли это как-то сделать без использования библиотеки os?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Не делайте так. Пишите ваши данные внутри каталога с вашей программой куда-то. Либо в пользовательский каталог. Писать абы куда у вас просто прав скорее всего не будет.

Можно использовать библиотеку pathlib:
folder_path = "C:/Games"
from pathlib import Path
Path(folder_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


Спасибо, проверю, если все будет работать, то еще раз спасибо
